# Updating proxy (details) in a used HttpClientHandler

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building a system that uses an external proxy provider with session support. My system is hitting the proxy at a sustained rate of about 10 simulteanous connections with average lifetime of about 2 seconds. After I'm done with a session I'd like to re-use the previously used HttpClientHandler for a few more runs before releasing all resources related to it to avoid socket exhaustion and avoid problems with DNS updates.

Since I do not wish to re-use the session I previously used I figured I could just replace the WebProxy instance of the handler. This will trigger an `InvalidOperationException` because the socket has already been used prior and it cannot be changed. Examining the WebProxy instance shows that I can update the ICredentials property but this appears to have no effects as when I re-use the handler it will show up w/ its previously used IP address.

At this rate, my system needs about 1200 HttpClientHandler instances to run at a sustained 10 simulteanous connections. This is due to [TIME_WAIT on closed sockets](https://serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html) and scaling up(in either more simulteanous connections or a shorter length per session) will probably become a problem.

Any ideas on what I can actually update the proxy credentials?

Comment: It seems to be that the design principles around HttpClient/HttpClientHandler are that once used, they are immutable. I tried updating the Credentials on the Proxy and even the Username on the Credentials and none of those take effect. I don't think it is possible without writing my own implementation on various parts myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpClient and HttpClientHandler become immutable objects after first use. It is not possible to update any of the settings once the first request has been fired.